# Accessing 32 bit hive in .Net Core Application

Tags: .net, windows, .net-core, registry

What is the correct way to access 32 bit registry hive on a 64 bit machine? I tried the following code to set some value in HKCU\Software 32 bit hive but it still gets the 64 bit hive. I couldnt find any alternate api to pass `RegistryView` enum, In C++ the Wow64 flag can be specified when opening/creating a key but I dont find similar usage in `Microsoft.Win32` library.

```
[SupportedOSPlatform("Windows")]
void SetValue()
{
    using var key = GetOrCreateKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, 
            RegistryView.Registry32,
            @"SOFTWARE\MyApp\Key"
            );
        
    key?.SetValue("Value", 1);
}

[SupportedOSPlatform("Windows")]
static RegistryKey? GetOrCreateKey(RegistryHive hive, RegistryView view, string keyPath)
{
    using var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive, view);
    var subKey = baseKey?.OpenSubKey(keyPath);
    if (subKey != null)
    {
        return subKey;
    }

    return baseKey?.CreateSubKey(keyPath);
}
```

On 64 bit machine, I want the value to be set on key on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\MyApp\Key` but its getting written on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp\Key`

Comment: *"it doesnt seem to work"* what does it do? Throw an error, do nothing, do something else? `OpenSubKey(keyPath)` will open as read-only, you need `OpenSubKey(keyPath, true)`, as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.opensubkey?view=net-6.0#microsoft-win32-registrykey-opensubkey(system-string))

Comment: Updated the description,  The api still gets me the 64 bit hive instead of 32 bit hive.  I couldnt find any examples making use of the `RegistryView` reading the 32 bit hive.

Comment: Doesn't make sense: you can follow the code here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/registrykey.cs,800 and see that the `view` does feed through to a call to the native `RegOpenKeyEx` the same as C++. How are you verifying what is happening anyway?

Comment: Since a .net library is already there for registry access wanted to try out first before using the pinvoke. I can still use the wow64 path in the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node` and that works too. But my question is why this API is not working as expected.